# Express is listening on port 3000 despite setting it to 80?

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, port, express-4

Running on Amazon EC2. The code was created automatically by express-generator.

To start the app I had to do this:

> sudo PORT=80 npm start

Then I added lines 14:

```
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 80);
```

And 66

```
http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
```

Now I can start the app by saying:

> sudo npm start

but it says - Express server listening on port 3000. I can access it from my browser, but why 3000

http://pastebin.com/bwcBHZaa

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "haha",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.13.2",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.5",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "express": "~4.13.1",
    "express-generator": "^4.13.1",
    "jade": "~1.11.0",
    "kerberos": "file:kerberos",
    "mongodb": "^2.0.52",
    "morgan": "~1.6.1",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: fyi, make sure you convert to a float. Env variables are strings. ie. `app.set('port', Number(process.env.PORT) || 80);`

Comment: Thanks, I did, but still saying 3000.

Comment: Check your package.json , maybe there's a default overriding your configuration there

Comment: There's also the possibility that in bin/www, the port might be reconfigured

Comment: Nothing in package.json, but you may be right about bin/www

Comment: did you add the PORT Environnements Variables in Elastic Beanstalk's Configuration ?

Comment: I'm not using Beanstalk, I'm using EC2, it should fall back on 80 since it says process.env.PORT or 80. I coped that line, I know I could've just said app.set('port', 80);

Comment: I suspect @ludo is correct, check that it's not been set in `bin/www`, (it gets set there by default when you use Express generator)

Answer (score 0):

I just had a flash idea. This same thing happened to me years ago.

The thing is, it's very complicated to bind to the port 80.

Either one of the two solutions will work, but I recommend the first one for simplicity.

1. Nginx

You can use a very simple nginx configuration to "re-route" port 3000 request to the port 80.

```
#etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mysite.conf

server {
        listen 0.0.0.0:80;
        server_name www.mysite.com mysite.com;
        location /  {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

}
```

2. Or, you can use IpTables NAT rerouting :

https://glassonionblog.wordpress.com/2011/04/08/tomcat-redirecting-traffic-from-port-8080-to-80-using-iptables/

---

I found that using nginx just worked better in general, for multiple reasons (e.g. in case you restart your server). Restarting your server means you have to reload ipTables on restart. If you want to automate this, that means you have to install iptables-restore. But it's awkward to configure with NAT rerouting tables.

Using nginx was just straight and simple.