# Meteor always listens on port 3000

Tags: node.js, meteor, webstorm

I created a new Meteor project in WebStorm on Windows 8.
In "Run/Debug Configurations" I set the port value to 3008, but when I run the app, it always works on port 3000.

[image]
[image]

Does anybody know where Meteor defines the port number or how can I change it?

I've searched the words "3000", "PORT" and "listen" in the entire project but they don't exist.

I've also seen these questions which didn't help me because they use Express which defines the port number hard-coded:
[Node.js/Express.js App Only Works on Port 3000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18008620/node-js-express-js-app-only-works-on-port-3000) ,
[Express is listening on port 3000 despite setting it to 80?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34404348/express-is-listening-on-port-3000-despite-setting-it-to-80)

Any help will be profoundly appreciated!

Comment: How did you try and set the port to 3008?

Comment: If you are running Meteor from the command line, just use `meteor --port 3008`. If you aren't using the command line to start Meteor, let us know and maybe we can help.

Comment: @Dominic Tobias I did it in "Run/Debug Configurations". I've added a screen shot to my question to be clear.

Comment: @Brett McLain I don't use command line. I run it through the triangular green "Run" button in WebStorm.

Comment: You can try setting the environment variable PORT to 3008 from the command line via `set PORT=3008` or within WebStorm: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7707329/set-node-js-environment-variables-in-webstorm

Comment: @Brett McLain I did set the environment variable PORT to 3008 within WebStorm as I mentioned. Anyway I tried right now to do it through command line and I ran it again but it's still listening on port 3000.

Comment: @Alon did you add it to the WebStorm environment variables section, or just to `http://localhost:3008`?

Comment: @Brett McLain in the first place I added it just to http://localhost:3008. However, now after you emphasized the difference, I added it also to the WebStorm environment variables section and ran the program again but it's still listening on port 3000. I added another picture to my question that shows that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try passing `-p 3008` as a program argument in Meteor run configuration:

[image]

http://localhost:3008 in `Browser/Live Edit` tab is just used for browser launching (i.e. it tells WebStorm to launch the browser with specified URL), it's not supposed to affect Meteor port in any way